# Deformation of $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, deformation-theory

I learnt that $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ is rigid, but can be deformed to a non-rigid Hirzebruch surface $S$. Suppose $\pi: M \to B$ is such deformation such that $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1 \cong M_{t_0}$ and $S \cong M_{t_1}$.

I want to understand the meaning of "rigidity". Does this mean that: 
(1) there exists an open set $t_0 \in U \subseteq B$, such that for all $t\in U$, $M_t \cong \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$? (Or maybe more strongly, $M_U \cong U \times (\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1)$?); or (2) only the first order deformation of $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ is trivial (because $H^1(\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1, \Theta)$ = 0), and it could well happen that no matter how $t \in B$ closes to $t_0$, $M_t$ may not isomorphism to $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$?

If (1) is the meaning of "rigidity", then I feel it is strange that for some $t$, $M_t$ "suddenly" becomes NOT the same as $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$. Moreover, I think the construction of aforementioned deformation is by considering extension of vector bundles $V, W$, and ${\rm Ext}^1(W,V)$ is the base $B$. So for $t \neq t_0$, the extension will never be trivial, and hence the corresponding variety should not be the same as $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$.

If (2) is the meaning of "rigidity", and suppose $\mathfrak{M} \to \mathfrak{B}$ is the Kuranishi family of $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$. Then I guess $T_{\mathfrak B, t_0} \cong H^1(\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1, \Theta) = 0$. But according to the previous discussion, $\mathfrak B$ is not of dimensional $0$. Hence $t_0$ must be singular at $\mathfrak B$. (By the way, is there a way to compute the dimension of Kuranishi space?)

My knowedge of deformation theory is floppy. Any comment/reference is very well appreciated!

Comment: The point is that in this case you do *not* have a separate moduli space, so it can happen  (and, in fact, it happens) that the variety is locally rigid but *not* globally rigid. 

The phenomenon you are talking about and the explicit description for the Kuranishi family of any Hirzebruch surface can be found in Catanese's paper *moduli of algebraic surfaces*, Theory of Moduli, Montecatini Terme, 1985, Springer LNM 1337 (1988).

Comment: Which moduli space are you talking about?

Comment: The variety $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ does not have a separate (=Hausdorff) moduli space. This allows the existence of a global deformation $\mathcal{X} \to \Delta$ such that $X_t \cong \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ for $t \neq 0$ and $X_0 \cong \mathbb{F}_2$.

In other words, the rigidity in this example is only local, not in the large.

Comment: Note that local rigidity is actually sufficient to imply that the Kuranishi family of $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ has $0$-dimensional basis. This gives in turn  $$H^1(\Theta_{\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1})=0$$ (this last condition is called *infinitesimal rigidity*).

Comment: Such deformation family is easy to construct, by considering a pencil of quadrics in $P^3$. An open subset in the base of this family corresponds to smooth quadrics (each isomorphic to $P^1\times P^1$), while finitely many points correspond to quadratic cones. If you consider a small resolution of singularities of the total family, the special fibers will turn into the Hirzebruch surface $F_2$.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi Thank you for you explanation! Do we always have the dimension of Kuranishi space $= H^1(X, \Theta_X)$? I feel the dimension could greater than that (otherwise, it is too easy to see a variety is rigid).

Comment: @Li Yutong: No, $H^1(X, \Theta_X)$ is the dimension of the *tangent space* at the point $[X]$ of the base $\textrm{Def}(X)$ of the semiuniversal deformation (=Kuranishi family). So the Kuranishi family has *at most* dimension $h^1(X, \, \Theta_X)$. If the strict inequality holds, than $\textrm{Def}(X)$ is singulat at $[X]$ and  $X$ is said to be *obstructed*.

Comment: You can find all of this and much more in Sernesi and Hartshorne books on deformation theory.

Comment: It's late to mention this, but I'm pretty sure the adjective Francesco wanted was "separated" not "separate".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rigidity means, if you have a family $F$ of surfaces such that one $f\in F$ of them is $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$, then there is an open set $U\subseteq F, U \ni f$ each of whom is $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$.

The source of confusion, I think, is in mixing up "family of varieties" with "moduli space of complex varieties with a fixed underlying real manifold" (or somesuch). In the latter, we want all the varieties to be nonisomorphic. Most families one meets are not of this type.

For a simpler example than yours, consider the conics $xy=t z^2$ in $\mathbb P^2$, $t\in \mathbb A^1$. They're all isomorphic except for $t=0$. I hope it seems less strange that $M_t$ is suddenly different there.

Comment: Thank you very much for you explanation! I have two questions according to your answer: (1) Does "moduli space of complex varieties with a fixed underlying real manifold" make sense in general? (2) Is this rigidity the same as "there exists a $U$ such that $F_U \cong U \times (\mathbf{P}^1 \times \mathbf{P}^1)$"? Or weaker than this locally triviality?

Comment: (1) Let me change it to: smooth proper families $F \to S$ with nonisomorphic fibers. In the complex case, all the fibers will be diffeomorphic. (2) I'm pretty sure I'd only expect etale-locally trivial (again, with $\mathbb P^1$-fiber for simplicity) but I don't have an example off the top of my head.